# Button onclick="function(x,y,z)"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to ask about the usage of the Onclick with three parameters function, but I have some trouble about the implementing the function into onclick,

```
var popupDiv1 = document.getElementById("popup_bg");

function openPopupMenu ()
{
   popupDiv1.style.display = "block";
}
```

above the function and the variable is my main and works well. the function blocks the display section which is stayed at #popup_bg and

```
<button id="button1" title="Press to Start" onclick="openPopupMenu ()">
```

when onclick this button popup became visable

but I would like to change that function into;

```
function start (x, y, z ){

 var x = document.getElementById(y);

 x.style.display = z;

}
```

But I have a trouble with this function to implementation to Onclick
these are ways which  I tried to implement;

```
onclick="start (z, 'popup_bg', 'block');"

onclick="start (z, 'popup_bg', 'block')"

onclick="start\'(z, 'popup_bg', 'block')\'"

onclick="start\'(z, "popup_bg", "block")\'"

onclick="start(z,'\'"popup_bg","block"\')"

onclick="start(\'z,'popup_bg','block'\')"

onclick="start(\' 'z, 'popup_bg', 'block' \')"
```

Comment: Please provide an [Minimal Complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is `z` in this case. Also, it looks like your `start` function overrides your first parameter anyway: `var x = ...`

Comment: the first parameter for the assigning and according to this assignment, changing that assigned variable.style.display section with z parameter to "block" or "none"  which is stayed at #popup_bg which will be "y" parameter.

Comment: @MehmetDURMUŞ No, the `z` in your `onclick`s

Comment: `onclick="start ('z', 'popup_bg', 'block');"` This should work. But the first parameter`'z'` will be overridden by your `start` function as pointed out by @putvande

Comment: it is a just variable name I just trying to assign and checking that is it works or not. I tried also different variables names in Onclick not only z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined the z argument when you set your on click function,, to solve it just remove that z argument that is not needed...

```js
var popupDiv1 = document.getElementById("popup_bg");



function start (y, z ){

 var x = document.getElementById(y);

 x.style.display = z;

}
```

```html
<div id="popup_bg" style="display:none;">this id the div</div>

<button id="button1" 
  title="Press to Start" 
  onclick="start ('popup_bg', 'block');">
hide
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to send x,y,z as **parameter** and those parameter should be enclosed with **quotes** or else you get undefined error for variable.

```js
function start(x,y,z){
var x = document.getElementById(y);
x.style.display = z;
}
```

```css
#popup_bg {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup_bg">
Content comes here
</div>
<button id="button1" title="Press to Start" onclick="start('z','popup_bg','block')">Click</button>
```

Comment: this is logically right but in my function, there is also a variable and changes every usage that means I mistake at the (x,y,z) and x there is not needed for the code works and thank you for concern.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this functionality i do not think that you need to have three parameters test the following code.

HTML:

```
<div id="showMe" style="display:none">Hi! It's working fine</div>

<button onClick="start('showMe', 'block')">Show</button>
<button onClick="start('showMe', 'none')">Hide</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function start(p2, p3)
{
    document.getElementById(p2).style.display = p3;
}
```

Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

your code should work if you get rid of x variable try this:

```
function start ( y, z ){

 var x = document.getElementById(y);

 x.style.display = z;

}

onclick="start ( 'popup_bg', 'block')"
```

Comment: Thank you so much and yes you are right and it's worked thanks :)